# Table alias + left join

Tags: php, mysql, nested-sets

So guys I'm trying to implement nested set model and I have the following query

```
SELECT 
    n.CategoryID, 
    CategoriesI18n.CategoryName, 
    COUNT(*)-1 AS level FROM Categories AS n, 
    Categories AS p LEFT JOIN CategoriesI18n ON (
        n.CategoryID=CategoriesI18n.CategoryID AND CategoriesI18n.Locale="en-US"
    ) WHERE n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND p.rgt GROUP BY n.lft ORDER BY n.lft;
```

When I select the tree I have to join CategoriesI18n table which is the multilanguage row for current category. But I get this error

```
Unknown column 'n.CategoryID' in 'on clause'
```

And I dont know why. Maybe Categories AS p overwrites the first alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out. Had to do nested select.

```
SELECT n.CategoryID, n.CategoryName, COUNT(*)-1 AS level 
    FROM (
        SELECT Categories.CategoryID AS CategoryID,  Categories.lft AS lft,  Categories.rgt AS rgt, CategoriesI18n.CategoryName AS CategoryName FROM Categories LEFT JOIN CategoriesI18n ON (Categories.CategoryID=CategoriesI18n.CategoryID AND CategoriesI18n.Locale="bg-BG")
        ) AS n, Categories AS p 
    WHERE n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND p.rgt GROUP BY n.lft ORDER BY n.lft;
```

Answer (score 0):

'Categories AS p LEFT JOIN CategoriesI18n',the joined Categories's alias is 'p',not 'n'

Comment: Well if I do this I get same name (name of the first parent category) for all children and sub children rows instead of their own. First row categories are ok with their names.

Comment: I think you can use 'inner join' instead of ','

Comment: Well I tried this SELECT n.CategoryID, CategoriesI18n.CategoryName, COUNT(*)-1 AS level FROM Categories AS n INNER JOIN Categories p ON (p.CategoryID=n.CategoryID) LEFT JOIN CategoriesI18n ON (p.CategoryID=CategoriesI18n.CategoryID AND CategoriesI18n.Locale="en-US") WHERE n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND p.rgt GROUP BY n.lft ORDER BY n.lft;

But now all categories return 0 for level ...